# Why does LinearModelFit give me an equation in $z$ rather than $x$?

Tags: fitting, variable-definitions

I am working on a Mathematica notebook and making graphs for my lab. I can't make a graph for my linearized data as `LinearModelFit` gives equation in `z` even though I pass `x` as an argument.

```
linfit = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
```

Comment: Use `ClearAll[x]` before `linfit =...`?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere/sometime before `LinearModelFit[data,x,x]` is invoked you must have defined `x` as `z`. To check if this is the case you can use [`ValueQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html):

```
ValueQ[x]
```

gives `True` if a value has been defined for `x`, and gives `False` otherwise. Alternatively, you can use

```
?x
```

which returns

[image]

if `x` is previously assigned a value, just the first line otherwise.

The following simple examples replicates your case:

```
x = z;
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
linfit = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
```

[image]

As a fix, you can use [`ClearAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html) to clear *all values, definitions, attributes, messages, and defaults associated with* `x` before using `x` in `LinearModelFit`:

```
ClearAll[x]
linfit = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
```

[image]